# What is chunkLen in MMS MessageType's fields

Tags: mms

I am developing the library that implements `mms` protocol fully. In [Message Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234813%28v=prot.10%29), we know that all messages must be started with `ChunckId`( i.e. [LinkMacToViewerPing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234785%28v=prot.10%29) ) . Could any one please tell me what is `ChunckId` and how can i fill it ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your subject says `chunkLen` but in the message body you say `chunckId`. Which one are you asking about?

If it's `chunkLen`, then take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234813.aspx for a description of what it is and how to set it.